# Implementing an add and remove function into my class

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, class

I have this code below that takes items of a PC and returns a quote, price etc. As of now, the only way that I can add or remove components is by directly modifying the array. Here is the code

```
class PriceCalc {

    Motherboard = 520.99;
    RAM = 250.4;
    SSD = 500.8;
    HDD = 400.66;
    Case = 375.5;
    Monitor = 600.75;
    Keyboard = 100.99;
    Mouse = 25.5;

    constructor(Obj) {

        this.parts = Obj;
        this.cost = "$" + Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0).toFixed(2);
        this.retail = "$" + (Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0) + Obj.reduce((a, b) => a + this[b], 0) * 1.75).toFixed(2);
        this.quote = "Your quote is " + this.retail;
    }
}

This is the key values
quote = new PriceCalc(["Motherboard", "RAM", "SSD", "HDD", "Case", "Monitor", "Keyboard", "Mouse"]);
console.log(quote.parts);
console.log(quote.cost);
console.log(quote.retail);
console.log(quote.quote);
```

What Id like to implement is a code as shown below that I can add within the class and call it to add new parts to the quote or remove existing parts.

```
function removePart(arr, part) {
    return arr.filter(function (ele) {
        return ele != part;
    });

} var result = removePart(["Motherboard", "RAM", "SSD", "HDD", "Case", "Monitor", "Keyboard", "Mouse"], "Mouse");
console.log(result)
```

I would like to implement it in a way where I can call this.parts (as stated in the previous code) and either call a new function that pushes new parts to "parts" or call a new function that removes certain parts that are already in the list. I hope what I've described makes sense

Here is s a general example template of what I mean, without the functional code:

```
class quote {
    constructor(/*...*/) {
        this.parts = ....
    }
    add() {
        //adds item
    }
    remove() {
        //removes item
    }
}

example = new quote(["part1", "part2"])
add(part3)
console.log(example) //returns ["part1" "part2" "part3"]
remove(part1)
console.log(example) //returns ["part2" "part3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
class quote {
    constructor(initialParts) {
        this.parts = initialParts
    }
    add(part) {
        this.parts = [...this.parts, part]
    }
    remove(part) {
        this.parts = this.parts.filter( p => p !== part)
    }
}

example = new quote(["part1", "part2"])
example.add('part3')
console.log(example) //returns ["part1" "part2" "part3"]
example.remove('part1')
console.log(example) //returns ["part2" "part3"]
```

If you want multiple of the same item you can still use an object and store the key as the name of the product and the number of items as the value. simply adjust the functions to account for this.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, this could be pretty helpful though with changing  the prices if duplicates were added

Comment: Ive implemented it into the code and it removes the items, but how could I make it  change the prices as well? ``

Comment: You want to be able to change the price and number of the items?

Comment: The idea is to implement it into the first code at the top which is a quotation calculator. I want to add or remove computer parts from the quote and return the prices

Comment: `quote4 = new PriceCalc(["RAM", "SSD", "Case", "Mouse"]);

console.log(quote4.parts);//Returns ["RAM", "SSD", "Case", "Mouse"]
console.log(quote4.cost);//Returns $1152.20
quote4.remove("Case");
console.log(quote4.parts);//Returns ["RAM", "SSD", "Mouse"]
console.log(quote4.cost);//Returns $1152.20`

Comment: quote4.remove("Case") removes the item from parts, but does not change the value of cost

Comment: create a lookup object for the parts to lookup up the prices and don't store it in the Quote class. Add a `totalPrice` member in the class so you can create a function that recalculates the price after every `remove` or `add` . This function just look's up the price from the global object of prices. does this help?

Comment: As in something like this.totalPrice = price?

Comment: Yes. after removal or addition of a part simply lookup the price of the part and adjust the `this.totalPrice` variable.